# Query Wordpress Database after AJAX Call - Getting an Error of Call to a member function get_results() on null

Tags: mysql, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to query the WP Database but I am receiving an error of `Call to a member function get_results() on null`. I believe I need to somehow register wpdb but despite reading through multiple similar questions I can't piece together what needs to be done. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am new and learning Wordpress and Ajax.

My JS file is called `zip-search-popup.js`

```
   (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.zip-bar-button').click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          submittedZip = $("#zipcode-bar-input").val();
          $.ajax({
            //need an automatic URL so that this doesn't need to be updated
            url: from_php.ajax_url,
            type: "GET",
            data: {
              action : 'zip_search',
              submittedZip : submittedZip,
            },
            success: function (response) {
              console.log(response);
              alert("working");
            }
          })
          $('.zip-search-popup-con').fadeToggle(350);
        })
        $('.zip-search-dismiss').click(function() {
          $('.zip-search-popup-con').toggle();
        })
      })
    })(jQuery);
```

I have registered my scripts in `functions.php` and have my SQL query function within here as well.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hyix_enqueue_custom_js');
function hyix_enqueue_custom_js() {
    //enqueue zip-search-popup.js
    wp_enqueue_script('zip-search-popup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/zip-search-popup.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_localize_script('zip-search-popup', 'from_php', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

//hook zip-search-popup function into ajax
add_action( 'wp_ajax_zip_search', 'ajax_zip_search' );
//same hook for users not logged in
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_zip_search', 'ajax_zip_search' );

  
//query for pulling in shipping data
function ajax_zip_search() {
  $submitted_zip = $_REQUEST['submittedZip'];
  global $wpdb;
  // The SQL query
  $response  =  $wpdb-> get_results("SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_name ".
              "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations ".
              "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones ".
              "ON {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations.zone_id = {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_id ".
              "WHERE location_code = '$submittedZip' ");

  $response = array(
    'request' => $_REQUEST,
    'zip' => $submitted_zip,
    'test' => 'is ok',
  );
  wp_send_json( $response );
  // echo $response;
  die();
}
```

Comment: how is `zip-search.php` loaded?

Comment: @mikerojas it isn't currently. It was working fine when I was calling it directly off of a form submission and not via Ajax. How should it be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

**You should use the [Wordpress-Way to use AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Ajax_in_Plugins)**

All Ajax-Request will be recieved by `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` which fires the Ajax-Hooks which run your PHP-Code. The Ajax-Hook depends from the `action`-parameter in your Ajax-Request.

With [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) you can provide some data from PHP to Javascript, i.e. the ajax_url.

Place this code in your `functions.php`. This include the code that handles your Ajax-Request.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hyix_enqueue_custom_js');
function hyix_enqueue_custom_js() {
    //enqueue zip-search-popup.js
    wp_enqueue_script('zip-search-popup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/zip-search-popup.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_localize_script('zip-search-popup', 'from_php', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}



add_action( 'wp_ajax_zip_search', 'ajax_zip_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_zip_search', 'ajax_zip_search' );

function ajax_zip_search() {
    
    $submitted_zip = $_REQUEST['submittedZip'];
    
    // do some zip search

    $response = array(
        'request' => $_REQUEST,
        'zip' => $submitted_zip,
        'test' => 'is ok',
        'foo' => 'bar'
    );
    
    wp_send_json( $response );
    
}
```

Now you can use the ajax_url provided by [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/). Don't forget to send an `action`-parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url: from_php.ajax_url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        action: 'zip_search',
        submittedZip: submittedZip
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      alert('it works');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still having difficulty getting it to work. I am now receiving a 400 error. I updated my original question to reflect the changes. I am now only running two files `zip-search-popup.js` and `functions.php`.

I am concerned it is a problem between a hyphen and an underscore and have tried a lot of different setups but nothing has gone through.